# List input in classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there any possibility to create a classifier in scikit-learn containing two lists / vectors and floats that would look like:

```
 np.array( [array([-0.01578492,  0.00320967, -0.041407  , -0.07682859, -0.01507759,
         0.02470386, -0.00886424,  0.05536039, -0.02744256,  0.02262186],
       dtype=float32)
 array([-0.01578492,  0.00320967, -0.041407  , -0.07682859, -0.01507759,
         0.02470386, -0.00886424,  0.05536039, -0.02744256,  0.02262186],
       dtype=float32)
 3.0 1.0 117.0 101.0 97.0 4.0 100.0 3.0 0.875 0.875 0.6 0.5])
```

When I am trying to run code with this model I am receiving a Typeerror

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\xxx\create_model.py", line 430, in <module>
    scaler.fit(X_train)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\bio_system\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 809, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight)
 
File "C:\Users\user\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 844, in partial_fit
    X = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\Users\user\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 577, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
  
File "C:\Users\user\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 856, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The shape of `x` and `y` is correct. Is it possible to combine types for features?  How can I fix it?

Comment: why don't you flatten it to a single dimension first?

Comment: I have no ideas what you try to do. Better show minimal working code, with example data and expected result.

Comment: usually models use flatten arrays - even if it 2D image - so maybe you should flatten it.